# How to send a reminder in bot framework

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am building a test bot using Microsoft's Bot Framework / Bot Builder for C#.NET / LUIS. It is deployed on Azure. The idea for my test project is to send a reminder to the user.

For example, when user have a meeting in 1 hour bot should reply "meeting in 1 hour", it should initiate a conversation or send a reply to the existing conversation in one hours.

I have no problem parsing natural language into date and task using LUIS, however I have no idea how to schedule a task so that the framework would somehow send a reply to the user later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look to the [AlarmBot sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot) as it showcases a similar scenario. Per the docs:

> The alarm bot sample illustrates several concepts:
>
> - modifying the dialog stack based on external events (e.g. the passage of time)
> - proactively messaging the user based on external events (e.g. the alarm is ringing)

Answer (score 0):

See [Get notification from bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) if you are using Bot Framework v4